# Drawing subgroup diagram of Dihedral group $D4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am reading Fraleigh p. 80 in A First 
Course in Abstract Algebra, and in the book i see the elements and subgroup diagram of the dihedral group $D_4$. Here are they:

[image]

[image]

Here is how i try to draw the subgroup diagram: p<sub>0</sub> must be included in every subgroup since it is identity element. Then i look at p<sub>1</sub>, and try to find the subgroups including p<sub>1</sub>, since p<sub>1</sub> is included, the inverse of it must be included also, and p<sub>1</sub>op<sub>1</sub> must be included also, and so on . I need to check whether the result of these computations make it closed. But this lookslike a very long process. Is there an easy way to do that? For example, by looking at u<sub>1</sub> can we immediately say that it is included or not in a subgrouo without checking all compositions of u<sub>1</sub> with u<sub>1</sub>? Or by looking at p<sub>1</sub> can we find < p<sub>1</sub> > easily? Thanks

Comment: This is because either $u_1p_1$ or $p_1u_1$ is not in it, assuming $D_4=u_1,u_1^2,u_1^3.u_1^4,p_1,p_1u_1,p_1u_1^2,p_1u_1^3$

Comment: yes, since it is not in the subgroup diagram i know it is not in it, but why?

Comment: group has to be closed under operation

Comment: Thanks, but checking all possibilities looks like takes very long time. Is there any short way to understand whether a composition is an element of D4?

Comment: There isn't many combinations. For instance, if $u_1$ is in it, then $\langle u_1\rangle$ is in it.

Comment: Yes, but it looks to me like finding  ⟨u1⟩ takes a long time. Is there any way to find it easily? Do we need to calculate all these composition permutations?

Comment: I tried ⟨u1⟩, ⟨u1⟩={p0, u1} and ⟨p2⟩={p0,p2}. But we see that {p0,p2,u1,u2} is also in it. So by checking ⟨a⟩, where a is in D4 we do not guarantee finding all subgroups? How do we find {p0,p2,u1,u2}?

Comment: just find all elements of order 2, then find all elements of order 4. Then list they generate when you put them together. Sometimes you'll get a new group sometimes it's one you've already seen, but you'll quickly fill up that subgroup lattice if you do this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Personally, I am familiar to the following presentation of $D_4$ (or $D_8$). I added it here maybe you find it easier. In fact, You can **feel** the elements in this presentation easier. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Geometric interpretation is convenient for $D_4$. It is the invariance group of the square.

$D_4$ has three $\frac{\pi}{2}$ rotations, making up the subgroup $R_0$, $R_1$, $R_2$, $R_4$ 
(replacing $\rho$ of the textbook of the original query with upper case $R$). It is also clear that $R_0$ and $R_2$ ($\pi$ radians rotations) make up a subgroup.

$M_1$ and $M_2$ can be taken to be reflections in lines joining the opposite sides of the square and $d_1$ and $d_2$ are reflections in the two diagonals. 
It is obvious that each of these four elements squared is the identity, making four more proper subgroups of order 2.

A little visualisation shows that $R_2$ has the property of exchanging $M_1$ and $M_2$ and separately $d_1$ and $d_2$. This explains the other order 4 subgroups in the figure from the textbook.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/39599) to improve your answer.