# Cayley Diagram subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, cayley-graphs

[image: Cayley Diagram]

I am working with this Cayley diagram. I have labeled it as shown. Dotted line is $a$ and solid is $b$. I am listing all the subgroups. I currently have:
$\{e,a\},\{e, ab\},\{e,ab^2\},\{e,ab^3\},\{e, ab^4\},\{e,b,b^2,b^3,b^4\}$ where $e$ is the identity element. Am I missing any subgroups?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subgroups of $D_4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532229/subgroups-of-d-4)

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek Would this not be $D_5$?