# Order of the Elements in $D_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am having trouble finding the order of each element in $D_4$.

I know $D_4 = \{R_0, R_{90}, R_{180}, R_{270}, V, H, D, D'\}$ and $|D_4| = 8$.

How would I go about finding the order of the elements?

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532229/subgroups-of-d-4) for its subgroups, hence the orders of elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the definition of order, which loosely means in this context: "how many times can you iterate one of the operations before everything is back to how it started?" For instance, $R_{90}$ refers to a rotation by 90 degrees. If we do that 4 times, our object is back to how it started, so the order of that element is 4.

Comment: so let me see if i have done this right: $|R_0| =1, |R_{90}|=4, |R_{180}|=2, |R_{270}|=4, |V|=1? |H|=1?, |D|=2, |D'|=2$

Comment: Not quite. A general hint: the *only* element of any group that can ever have order 1 is the identity element, which you've called $R_0$ here.

Comment: are my answers for the rotations right? i was having trouble with $V, H, D, D'$

Comment: You've got the rotations right, yes.

Comment: does $|V| =2, |H|=2, |D|=2, |D'|=2$?

Comment: Yep! You've got it.

Answer (score -1):

The Dihedral Group D4 has representation $ \{I,A,B,C,D,E,F,G\} $ which
$ I= 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 
  \end{bmatrix} $,
$ A=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & -1 \\
    1 & 0 
  \end{bmatrix} $,
$ B= 
\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 
  \end{bmatrix} $,
$ C=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    -1 & 0 
  \end{bmatrix} $,
$ D=
\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 0 \\
     0 & 1 
  \end{bmatrix} $,
$ E=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 
  \end{bmatrix} $,
$ F=
\begin{bmatrix}
     1 & 0 \\
     0 & -1 
  \end{bmatrix} $,
$ G=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & -1 \\
   -1 & 0 
  \end{bmatrix} $

By multiplication of Matrices, the order of each element is
$ |I|=1 $, $ |A|=4 $, $ |B|=2 $, $ |C|=4 $, $ |D|=2 $, $ |E|=2 $, $ |F|=4 $, $ |G|=2 $.

Comment: Note that $F$ has order $2$ and not $4$.